# Spyder - Question about execution of multiple lines of script

Tags: spyder

I am a new python user. Happened to encounter a question when executing this:

```
1 + 1
2 + 2
3 + 3
Out: 6
```

As seen the console would only show the result of 3+3. If I add print() for each line, all three calculations would be printed out.

Wondered if there is any way I can execute multiple calculations over lines without adding print()?

Thank you!